# Save <div> content to html file

Tags: jquery, save, output

I have a `<div>` on my page that is constantly updated every 3 seconds. I'm using `setInterval` and `AJAX` to do this and update the `<div>`.

I've added a button that saves the current `<div>`'s data and writes it into a .html` file and then downloads it, but it's not working well across browsers.

In Chrome this works:

```
$("#save").click(function () {
    $('<a/>').attr({
          download: 'export.html', 
          href: "data:text/html," + $('#result').html() 
    })[0].click()
});
```

But it doesn't work in IE11, Firefox or Edge, it fails to do anything. In Safari it works but changes the current active page to `export.html` instead of downloading the `export.html` file.

Is there a way to do this that will work across browsers. Have the `<div>` output written to a html file and have it downloaded?

Thanks.

Comment: maybe you'll need some server side code.

Comment: @PEJK Please can you explain.

Comment: refer this  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery)

Comment: This may explain why it's not working http://caniuse.com/#feat=download

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'm reading through the links, but I'm not sure how this applies as I'm trying to get the output from a  DIV.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated my script to write the output shown in the DIV to a temp file on the server.  The page then shows a download link and a backend download script gets the temp file and downloads it. This seems to work OK.